# Make only a bone follow a path?

Tags: animation, armature, bones, constraints

Is it possible to just make a specific bone and its children follow a path via the Follow Path constraint, and not the whole armature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the follow path constraint modifier to the bone in the bone constraint properties.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't see that button!